# html/php force text to stay on one line as long as possible

Tags: php, html

http://puu.sh/8pRqd.png
http://puu.sh/8pRtQ.png

as you can see from those 2 screenshots the text doesnt start on one line all the time. its random all the time, one time the dvdr will have a linebreak after it and one time it will just continue on the same line. i dont know why it does this. i want it to be forced to go for as long as it can on the row before going down another one.

take the 2nd picture:
what i want it do to: display the text like the 720p line is
what i dont want it to do: display the text like the dvdrip line is.

none of the codes hold any linebreaks, non of the database entries hold one. so how do i force it to stay on one line for as long as it can?

```
if (!empty($rel_720p)) {echo "<li><strong>720p:</strong> " . $rel_720p . "</li>";}
if (!empty($rel_dvdr)) {echo "<li><strong>DVD:</strong> " . $rel_dvdr . "</li>";}
if (!empty($rel_1080p)) {echo "<li><strong>1080p:</strong> " . $rel_1080p . "</li>";}
if (!empty($rel_dvdrip)) {echo "<li><strong>DVDrip:</strong> " . $rel_dvdrip . "</li>";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `white-space: nowrap;` on your containers CSS, as well as defining minimum and maximum widths for browser sizes. In this instance, the `<li>` tags.

Comment: yuck. i hate fighting with css code. ill just remove the list tags and do it on one entire row. thanks for the answer though